# Can the employment reference letter include the purpose of my visit for a Canadian visit visa?

Tags: visas, canada, conferences, proof-of-employment

My company wants me to attend a conference in Canada, should the employment reference letter include the purpose of the visit and details of their funding? (they will fund the trip).
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canadian immigration will want to know a number of things about your trip including:

- The purpose of your visit
- who is paying for your visit
- If you have permission from your work to make the visit
- That you will not be doing illegal work

They also need evidence to back up all these points. If you are travelling for work, a letter from your employer should help back up all of these, and so should state all of them. Stating what you are doing for them should cover the last point.